# Insert directives from custom filters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-filters

Is it possible to insert directives from within custom filters?

For example given the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.0.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello <span ng-bind-html="name | test"></span>!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.filter('test', ['$sce', function($sce){
  return function(val) {
    var out = '<b>' + val + '</b>';
    out += '<uib-progressbar value="55">55</uib-progressbar>';
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(out);
  }
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

How do I get the "uib-progressbar" to display properly as a progress bar?

From what I've read I'll need to manually $compile the directive and then append the resulting element to the page but to do that the rest of the html (generated in the filter) will need to be rendered first, so it's kind of impossible from what I can see?

I've set up a plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/V5SmmQXPdrfKeVEbNwaV?p=preview

Comment: Bingo. It's impossible. And also I'd venture to say undesirable. In what situation would you want to use a filter for this?

Comment: I'd say it is possible, but pointless. I also have the same question as @MicahWilliamson asked.

Comment: @sdfacre I don't think filters can return dom elements though (html: yes, dom: no). If they can't return dom elements then you won't be able to $compile them.

Comment: @MicahWilliamson, you can pass the outer element to the filter and do the compile and append inside the filter. As I said, doable, but pointless. Anyway, at least we are on the same page that the filter shouldn't be used like this.

Answer (score 0):

Filetrs are not for this, write directive instead, like:

```
app.directive('test', function() {
  return {
    restrict : 'E',
    template : function(elem, attrs) {
      var out = '<b>' + attrs.val + '</b>';
      out += '<uib-progressbar value="55">55</uib-progressbar>';
      return out;
    }
  }
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/oQ0AekzCBjd9eiNqhL6c?p=preview